# Geting incorrect $index value for parent ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

I have following code and try to use $index in delete function but it gives incorrect value of it.

```
  <li ng-repeat="joinMember in data.teamMember  | orderBy:'member.screenName || member.fname' ">
                  <div class="member-list-img">
                    <a ng-href="">
                      <img ng-src="{{joinMember.member.data.image ? (joinMember.member.data.imageType == 'avatar' ? '/public/images/avatars/' + joinMember.member.data.image : '/public/images/' + joinMember.member.data.image) : '/public/images/avatars/avatar-73.png'}}" width="100%" alt="{{joinMember.member.screenName ? joinMember.member.screenName : joinMember.member.fname + ' ' + joinMember.member.lname }}" />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="member-list-cont">
                    <h4>
                      <a ng-href="#">
                        {{joinMember.member.screenName ? joinMember.member.screenName : joinMember.member.fname + ' ' + joinMember.member.lname }}
                      </a>
                    </h4>
                    <span>{{joinMember.created | date : "MMMM d, y"}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-if="data.canModify" class="membr-delete">
                    <a ng-href="">
                      <i class="fa fa-trash text_link" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="deleteTeamMember($parent.$index, joinMember.id)"></i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Why is it incorrect ? what are you expecting and what are you getting ? 
By the way your problem is angularjs related and not angular.
Try `$index` instead of `$parent.$index`

Comment: There are one more ng-repeat and i wnat to pass that in function deleteTeamMember() but its not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $parent.$index in a div that have ng-if tag. which delete dom element(div) if condition is fall so that case you will receive incorrect $index value. but with ng-show it only add hide class to that div.

So try to ng-show if it is not important to remove div element instead just hide it.

Note:- You are also using orderBy filter in ng-repeat which will sort in only your DOM so if you will find incorrect object value in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the directive ng-if creates a new scope for itself, when you refer to $parent, it access the immediate $parent's scope, i.e., the inner repeat expression's scope.

So if you want to achieve something you wanted like in the former, you may use this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2">
        <div ng-if="1">
            ({{$parent.$parent.$index}} {{$parent.$index}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you have more than one inner directives, you can use ng-init for storing $index in a variable for references in child scopes.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list" ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2" ng-init="innerIndex=$index">
        <div ng-if="1">
            ({{outerIndex}} {{innerIndex}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So try $parent.$parent.$index in your example and please check [understanding the scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the official documentation of angularjs you should get a zero-based index via $index within a ng-repeat. Try the example by angularjs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#examples). Try to debug `data.teamMember` in your controller to make sure that this is the correct array you'd like to iterate.